# Proof of Noether's Normalization theorem.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

As [stated here](http://people.brandeis.edu/~igusa/Math101bS07/Math101b_notesB2b.pdf), Noether's Normalization Theorem states:

*Suppose that $R$ is a finitely generated integral domain over a field $K$. Then there exists an algebraically independent subset $\{y_1,y_2,y_3,\dots,y_r\}\in R$ such that $R$ is integral over $K[y_1,y_2,y_3,\dots,y_r]$*.

If I correctly understand the statement, $R$ is a $K$-algebra, such that if $ab=0$, then $a=0$ and/or $b=0$. Let its generators be $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$. Then $K[a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n]=R$. $R$ is integral over itself. Hence, $R$ is integral over $K[a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n]$.

1. Is my reasoning correct?
2. Does this count as proof of Noether's Normalization Theorem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The generators $\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ need not be algebraically independent.

Comment: @ZevChonoles- sorry this might be a stupid question, but my logic was: if $a_k=$ some combination of the other generators, then every element in $R$ can anyway be constructed by $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}\setminus \{a_k\}$. So $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}\setminus \{a_k\}\subset \{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$ can also be the set of generators.. Is it possible to construct an algebraically independent set of generators this way?

Comment: Ok sorry found a counterexample to my own question. If $\{a,b,c\}$ are the generators, and $a^2=b^3c^4$, then $a$ can't be removed from the list of generators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The theorem requires the $y_i$ to be algebraically independent. Your "proof" doesn't even mention this condition. So no, it is not correct.

Comment: @ChrisEagle- Thanks for your answer!